# Is this sequence a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Consider a continuous mapping $f: X \rightarrow X$, where $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and convex.

Consider a sequence $\{x_k \in X\}_{k \geq 0}$ such that for all $k \geq 0$ and $h \geq 1$,
$$x_ {k+h} - x_k = \frac{1}{k+h} \left(  f(x_{k+h-1})+ ...+ f(x_k) - h x_k \right). $$

Is the sequence $\{x_k\}_k$ Cauchy? If not, under what additional conditions on $f$ does it?

Comment: So $\left\|  x_ {k+1} - x_k \right\| = \frac{1}{k+1} \left\|  f(x_k) - f(x_k) \right\| = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo: the last guy is $x_k$, not $f(x_k)$.

Comment: So you get $\left\| x_{k+1} - x_k \right\| = \frac{1}{k+1} \left\| f(x_k) - x_k \right\|$.

Comment: In particular, after the crucial modification to the question, for every $k\geqslant1$,
$$
kx_k=x_1+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(x_n).
$$

Comment: Yes, correct: $x_k = \left( \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} f(x_n) \right) + \frac{x_1}{k}$. Also $x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} f(x_n) $ (because $x_1 = f(x_0)$). Now I would need conditions on $f$ such that $x_k$ converges.

Comment: For instance, the claim holds if $f$ is linear.